# jQuery carousel with pager in Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, carousel, pager

I'm looking for a good jQuery carousel for Drupal.

**Requirements:**

- it has to have a pager (a mini navigation where people can choose which slide they want to see)
- compatible with Drupal 6
- compatible with jQuery
- when the user hovers on the slide, the user should see a new div
- content must be filled with Drupal variables.

I found the [jQuery UI Carousel](http://drupal.org/project/uicarousel), but there is no pager with it (or do I overlook this one). Then I stumbled upon [these](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html), do you think it's compatible/configurable with Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the *[jQuery Tools](http://drupal.org/project/jquerytools)* module, it's in development status so you better try it yourself.

My suggestion is to use the *[Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)* module.

Second comes *[Dynamic display block](http://drupal.org/project/ddblock)* (which is harder to configure).

Answer (score 0):

[bxSlider 4](http://bxslider.com/) integrates very well with Drupal via jQuery.

**Important**:

1. Do not use the version 3 that introduces issues to [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) + [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox).
2. You will need to have the [jQuery Update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your Requirements may fully implement by both  https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarouselthumbs and https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel